# Show all items if no result matches the key

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In JQuery auto complete I want to show all results if none matches the key entered. Also I need to restrict the `minLength` to **3**.

This is my code. I've checked for `ui.content.length === 0` and triggered `$(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())` but it isn't working.

```
$( "#example" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength:3,
      response: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
          $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: To clarify, if there is a partial match, you want it to show the results. If there is a 0 matches, you want it to show all possible results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution for you:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 3,
    response: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.content.length === 0) {
        $.each(availableTags, function(i, v) {
          ui.content.push({
            label: v,
            value: v
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7gpLtq6c/

If it's empty, we just push all the potential results back into the array.